# pandas timeseries offset BusinessMonthBegin doesn't roll over on the new month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a couple of pandas functions that I use to collect relative start dates for previous time periods. I noticed today on the start of the new month, my business month start (`BMS`) function returned an unexpected timestamp:

```
# so.py
import pandas
import time

def now(format='ms', normalize=True):
    obj = pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/Toronto').normalize()
    if normalize == False:
        obj = pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/Toronto')
    if format == 'ms':
        obj = int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) * 1000)
    return(obj)

def BMS(multiplier, format='ms'):
    obj = now(format=None) + pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(multiplier)
    obj = pandas.Timestamp(obj).floor(freq='D')
    if format == 'ms':
        obj = int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) * 1000)
    return(obj)

print(f'my function: {BMS(-4, format=None)}')

# python3 so.py
2021-10-01 00:00:00-04:00
#
```

`2021-10-01 00:00:00-04:00` is unexpected, because this timestamp was the same timestamp that was returned yesterday:

```
yesterday = pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/Toronto').normalize() - pandas.Timedelta(days=1)
print(f'yesterday: {yesterday + pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(-4)}')

# yesterday: 2021-10-01 00:00:00-04:00
```

Since today is a new month, I would expect `BMS(-4, format=None)` to return
`2021-11-01 00:00:00-04:00`

In case it might be necessary, a more basic `mre` to re-produce what my functions are doing is like so:

```
# MRE
today = pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/Toronto').normalize()
print(f'mre: {today + pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(-4)}')
```

**Update**
This morning, the `mre` returned the expected timestamp

```
2021-11-01 00:00:00-04:00
```

Since it rolled over on the second day of the month and not the first day of the month, maybe there's an implicit inclusion of the first day of the month when calculating `BusinessMonthBegin`?

What am I missing?

Comment: side note, do not use `int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) * 1000)` - that just happens to be correct if `obj` is in the same time zone as your OS is configured to use. Use `obj.timestamp()*1000` instead.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks.  Side note noted :)

Comment: regarding your actual question, I think the problem is that 2022-02-01 is on the offset, i.e. it is a business month start date. You could check for that in your BMS function (e.g. by comparing to `pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin().rollback`) and do `multiplier += 1` if that is the case and `multiplier` is negative. But I'm not totally sure this is your desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date falls on the offset, the offset addition already gives the previous bmonth start date (e.g. 2022-02-01 is a business month start date):

```
import pandas as pd

t_on_offset = pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01')
t_after_offset = pd.Timestamp('2022-02-02')

## on the offset, the offset addition will go back one month already:
t_on_offset + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(-1)
# Timestamp('2022-01-03 00:00:00')

# it seems what you actually want here is
# t_on_offset + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(0)

# this just rolls back to the beginning of the BM:
t_after_offset + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(-1)
# Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00')
```

You can check if you're on the offset like

```
pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin().rollback(t_on_offset) == t_on_offset
# True

pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin().rollback(t_after_offset) == t_after_offset
# False
```

So in your example BMS function (slightly refactored), that could look like

```
def BMS(timestamp, multiplier, normalize=True, format='ms'):
    if pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin().rollback(timestamp) == timestamp:
        if multiplier < 0:
            multiplier += 1
    obj = timestamp + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthBegin(multiplier)
    
    if normalize:
        obj = obj.normalize()

    if format == 'ms':
        return obj.timestamp() * 1000

    return(obj)
```

In action:

```
for t in pd.Timestamp('2022-01-31'), pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-02-02'):
    print(f'{str(t)} -> my function: {BMS(-4, t, format=None)}')
    
2022-01-31 00:00:00 -> my function: 2021-10-01 00:00:00
2022-02-01 00:00:00 -> my function: 2021-11-01 00:00:00
2022-02-02 00:00:00 -> my function: 2021-11-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I see more clearly now from the docs how the `.rollback()` method relates to offsets.  This is what I was missing.  Thanks.